# Using a PHP variable as a variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm having a hard time understanding how to import a specific variable for use with jQuery.

Some links on a Wordpress theme are using

```
<?php  if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "portfolio_link", true) ): ?> 
            <h1 class="portfolio-title">
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php the_field('portfolio_link'); ?>">
                    <?php the_field('portfolio_title'); ?> <span class="sosa-icon">p</span>
                </a>
            </h1>
            <!--get PDF if not empty-->
        <?php else: ?>
            <h1 class="portfolio-title"><?php the_field('portfolio_title'); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see the href is set as

```
href="<?php the_field('portfolio_link'); ?>"
```

Now I have a jQuery script as follows

```
    <script>
  <?php  if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "portfolio_link", true) ): ?> 
  <?php

$phpVar = 'http://www.google.com';
  echo "var phpVariable = '{$phpVar}';";

?>
  jQuery(".box").click(function() {

    window.open(phpVariable);
});

  <?php endif; ?>
</script>
```

This script currently works. It opens google in a new tab as a placeholder until I know how to make it open the same result as the href.

Now what I can't understand is how to set '$phpVar' to have the same effect as the 'href' I showed before instead of 'http://www.google.com';

Comment: `window.location.href = phpVariable;`

Comment: the window.open(phpVariable); is fully functional. My issue is that I don't know how to set that variable to be the same as href="<?php the_field('portfolio_link'); ?>"

Comment: `$('.box').attr('href', phpVariable);`

Comment: or `$phpVar = the_field('portfolio_link');`

Comment: do you want track by php which link was clicked ? i dont understand what exactly you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure just how the WordPress handling of this is, but given that `the_field('portfolio_title');` returns a valid URL, you can simply assign the JavaScript variable the output of this variable.

```
var phpVariable = "<?php the_field('portfolio_link'); ?>";
```

Comment: Your comment just helped me get it! Thank you. 

I added your line of code into the click function and it worked exactly as I need it.

Comment: The final function looks like this for anyone who may need it:

jQuery(".box").click(function() {
    var phpVariable = "<?php the_field('portfolio_link'); ?>";
    window.open(phpVariable);
});

Comment: I'm not sure if I should open a new question or ask here. This does work but I noticed if I have adblock disabled, it will open every link on the page at the same time.

Comment: @MartynJH That is not related to the question here. To be able to solve that you'd need to provide information about the loop (if there is loop) as well as where `.box` is in the markup. It is not solvable given the information provided here.